# OpenSSl returns bad signature on verification in the newer version and OK in old version

Tags: openssl, certificate, bouncycastle, signature, verify

I am trying to verify a certificate I created using BoucyCastle library in C#, with OpenSSL command openssl verify. The certificate was accepted by the browser and verification using OpenSSL 0.9.8 returned OK. But when verifying using OpenSSL 1.1.1 I get the following error:

```
error:04091068:rsa routines:int_rsa_verify:bad signature
```

What might be the problem with the certificate?

What are the differences between the two versions of the OpenSSL regarding verification function?